# Number of login sessions for a time period in Intersystems Cache database

Tags: database, security, intersystems-cache, intersystems

This question is related to Intersystems Cache Database. I want to know all the new users that got created for a particular time period. Also, Is there a way to figure out number of logins for a given time period?

Answer (score 1):

Both these events are being logged into the Audit database. That is, if you installed your instance in Lockdown mode. For minimal you have to enabled both auditing and the logging of %Login events. For normal, you have to enable the logging of %Login events.

You can then query the Audit database for the information you seek (and much more)

Cheers!